# Talend 10 GB input and lookup out of memory error

Tags: out-of-memory, lookup, talend

I'm new to Talend and trying to migrate a simple process from existing ETL into Talend ETL. The process itself is

Input file-->tMap (few string manipulation and lookup)-->write output

Lookup file has 3 columns (long, 1 char string, 2 char string). Long value is the key. Size of input and lookup file (each around 10GB). Server spec is 16 core (2.9GHz) 64GB RAM 8GB swap running linux.

I executed the job with Xmx/Xms values of 30g,45g,50g but each time failed with either GC overhead limit reached or Out of heap space. Tried using "Store temp data" to "true" and changing values of buffer size in tMap to a bigger number. That didn't help either.

Anyone faced such issues with large size lookups in Talend?

Thanks

Comment: This is the limit of Talend data integration, if such case we try to make the processing in the SGBD side not in Talend. I think you need to try with ELT tools or may be you stream the file with a custom code component.

Comment: @54l3d Thanks for that. Unfortunately using database is out of question for now. Out of curiosity, when you said "in such cases" - what is the max you've managed with Talend Data Integration and server spec for file processing?

Comment: Less than 100 megabytes, this is not the exact limit of Taland but what i worked with

Answer (score 1):

Like @Th_talend say try to filter column.

You can try this too (if you can):

- Store your file in temporary table and after you make the join directly with SQL in one input in order to work with the SGBD and not talend (tmap).

Answer (score 0):

Bring only the required columns into tMap from lookup by using tcolumnfilter.

did you give  the temp storage data

Comment: lookup only has 3 fields - one key and two fields that i'm looking up for - so yes it only has what is needed

Answer (score 0):

You can split the lookup file into manageable chunks (may be 500M), then perform the join in many stages for each chunk. This is surely work and you dont need a custom code neither an external tool, but it may have a bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use 30g,45g,50g for xms and xmx

try the below combo

xms   XMS

4GB   8GB

5GM   10GB

8GM   16GB

Dont you have Hadoop?